# How to configure properly CORS on sailsjs api

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My app is consisting from angularjs on frontend and sailsjs on backend. I am trying to configure CORS on my backend, but without success. I want that backend on address api.example.com is accessible only from frontend from address blog.example.com. My settings on sails config/cors.js are:

```
allRoutes: false,
origin: 'http://blog.example.com',
credentials: true,
methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
headers: 'content-type'
```

Result is, that my backend is freely accessible if I type to browser address bar api.example.com, but NOT from my frontend! In Chrome I get answer: "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ' '", Firefox sends just empty Response Body. I tried to configure cors in config/routes.js too, but also no success.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You want `allRoutes: true` unless your enabling cors on a route by route basis.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors

Comment: Thank you, Meeker! You helped me finally understand CORS logic and principle. I was in confusion "translating" what means "allRoutes" in cors.js. I thought, that it enables/disables access to backend from other addresses ("routes") as my frontend address. But now I understood, that it adjusts from which routes cross-origin request from origin blog.example.com is allowed to answer.